# How do we display a photo from Picasa java API?

Tags: java, picasa

Okay, it seems to be a stupid question, since we have [this](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)

However, up to the moment, I can only succeed in displaying the thumbnails by using:

```
PhotoEntry photo = //somehow I get the instance
photo.getMediaThumbnails().get(0).getUrl()
```

The biggest photo I can display through this method is up to 300 pixel or so[which is `photo.getMediaThumbnails().get(3)`]. How can I display the a thumbnail up to 400 pixel or even 800 pixel? Or How can I even refer back to the google picasa page that can actually help me display this photo?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that only few people use picasa api.. lol..

Comment: how to get picasa in your app..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following was answered by a community member of google picasa api:

> Take a look at
>
> http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/reference.html#Parameters
>
> It explains how you can control the
>   size of the image that the
>   media:content link points to as well
>   as how you can request different
>   thumbsizes for the media:thumbnail
>   links. Also listed are the valid size
>   values available. Note though, that
>   you can only access images up to 800px
>   in size (width or height, whatever is
>   larger) from websites.
>
> For instance:
>
> GET
>   /feed/api/user//albumid/?
>   kind=photo&imgmax=800&thumbsize=512,400,160c
>
> will give you a link to an 800px
>   version in the media:content link, a
>   link to the uncropped 512px and 400px
>   version in the first two
>   media:thumbnail elements and a
>   square-cropped 160x160 thumbnail in
>   the third thumbnail element.
>
> Cheers, Detlev

Answer (score 9):

Quite Simple

```
 PhotoEntry photo = //somehow I get the instance
    photo.getMediaThumbnails().get(0).getUrl()
```

You can use this way to get that 400/800px photo.

You only have to change the result URL that is given.
Change the s144/s400/s800  value of the URL

```
BLAH com/_BwderBVv7wg/XXXXXXXXX/AAAAAAAAAME/HdXja0HclK0/s72/DSC09176.JPG
BLAH com/_BwderBVv7wg/XXXXXXXXX/AAAAAAAAAME/HdXja0HclK0/s144/DSC09176.JPG
BLAH com/_BwderBVv7wg/XXXXXXXXX/AAAAAAAAAME/HdXja0HclK0/s288/DSC09176.JPG
BLAH com/_BwderBVv7wg/XXXXXXXXX/AAAAAAAAAME/HdXja0HclK0/s400/DSC09176.JPG
BLAH com/_BwderBVv7wg/XXXXXXXXX/AAAAAAAAAME/HdXja0HclK0/s800/DSC09176.JPG
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Picasa Java API and need to get image URL after uploading try to use following code

```
    try {
        File photoFile = new File(getFileName());
        service = new PicasawebService(applicationName);
        MediaFileSource photoMedia = new MediaFileSource(photoFile, "image/jpg");
        URL albumPostUrl = new URL(String.format("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/%1$s/albumid/%2$s", getUserName(), getAlbumId()));
        PhotoEntry returnedPhoto = service.insert(albumPostUrl, PhotoEntry.class, photoMedia);

        String href = returnedPhoto.getHtmlLink().getHref();

        if (returnedPhoto.getMediaContents().size() > 0) {
            // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!This is exactly JPEG URL
            href = returnedPhoto.getMediaContents().get(0).getUrl();
        }
        logger.info(String.format("Image published: <%s>", href));
        return href;
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `returnedPhoto.getMediaContents().get(0).getUrl()` gave me what I wanted for my uploaded pngs too.  It's the direct link that I can use for hotlinking, embedding, etc.

Comment: Alas, this seems to be limited to about 512 pixels on a dimension as well.