# Get Picasa's image direct URL using gdata-java-client

Tags: java, gdata-api, picasa

I upload image to Picasa and get response:

```
PhotoEntry returnedPhoto = myService.insert(feedUrl, PhotoEntry.class, myMedia);
```

Now I want to extract direct URL of an image. If I do...

```
for (Link link : returnedPhoto.getLinks()) {
    System.out.println(link.getHref());
}
```

...I get correct URLs, but they are indirect, e.g. `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/blablabla` Such URL points not to image-file, but to Picasa page with this image inside.

And what I want to get is URL like this one: `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/blablabla/blablabla/blabla/bla/my_image.jpg`

I've figured out that .Net users can do this using some class "PicasaQuery". But I guess this class is present only in .Net version, because I can't find it in gdata-java-library. How can I extract direct URL of an image in other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9379813/1492977) will help you.

```
PhotoEntry returnedPhoto = myService.insert(feedUrl, PhotoEntry.class, myMedia);
String href = returnedPhoto.getHtmlLink().getHref();
if (returnedPhoto.getMediaContents().size() > 0) {
  href = returnedPhoto.getMediaContents().get(0).getUrl();
}
System.out.println(href);
```